# NSInvalidArgumentException [NSURL length] url video record iphone

Tags: iphone, url, mpmediaplayercontroller

I save a video via iphone database application,the url where i'm recording the video is:

file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/0DB3ABFC-1630-44FF-8506-4B08E3CB2C85/tmp/capture-T0x2591d0.tmp.00fEdr/capturedvideo.MOV

However, when I try to read the video via MediaPlayer it always crashes...

sample code:

```
NSString *frameName = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:frameName];

videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self.view addSubview:videoPlayer.view];

videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 419);
[videoPlayer play];
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the contents of `[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"]` is not valid.

If it is valid, try `fileURLWithPath` rather then `urlWithString`.

Comment: [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"] seems valid when look value he is equal : file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/0DB3ABFC-1630-44FF-8506-4B08E3CB2C85/tmp/capture-T0x2591d0.tmp.00fEdr/capturedvideo.MOV   with NSLog..